# Радикал, радикальный.

Tags: этимология, семантика

Объясните, пожалуйста, происхождение и значение слова радикальный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Радика́л - буквально: «коренной» от лат. radix — «корень»), т.е. решительный. Радикальные меры - решительные, крайние.

2.Радикал - принадлежащий к течению радикализма.

Радикализм по Ожегову:
Политическое направление и движение (левое), ориентирующееся на проведение частичных демократических реформ в рамках существующего государственного строя.

Радикальный по Ожегову: решительный, коренной; придерживающийся крайних взглядов.

3.В мат. - знак извлечения корня.

4.В химии - устойчивая группа атомов.

Comment: А разве слова коренной и решительный - синонимы?

Comment: В значении "в корне"да - в корне поменять, решительно и бесповоротно, или под корень уничтожить - беспощадно.

Answer (score 0):

РАДИКАЛЬНЫЙ, - решительный, КОРЕННОЙ, наиболее действенный, от radicalis (лат.) - коренной, корневой. Радикальный - это изменяющий основы (КОРЕНЬ) вещей.

В русском языке слово "радикальный" известно с конца 18 века (из фр. языка), в словарях с 1806 года. В 1833-1834 гг. Пушкин в "Путешествии из Москвы в петербург" употребляет слово "радикализм". Слово "радикал" - в словарях  с 1865 года.